# What do Zebras sell?

Tags: kittens-game

I just found zebras to trade with.

```
Zebras
Attitude: hostile
Buys: slab (50)
Sells: iron (340 - 368)
plate (2 - 3)
titanium (1 - 1)
```

I don't really get how it works what Zebra's sell.

Do I get Iron, Plate and Titanium for 50 slab(and obviously the gold/catpower)? Or do I only get 1 of the resources, and is that random?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get iron every time, and plates 65% of the time. Titanium is even more rare, and also not a fixed chance. Note that the chances are independent; you can get all three at the same time.

The titanium chance is a base 15%, plus another 0.35% per Trade Ship owned. Also, [if the zebras hate you for no reason](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/184416/50582), the titanium chance is skipped entirely.

Comment: Plates are not certain. The chance is 65 instead of 100 for certain trades.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Billy's answer, the amount of titanium you get if you pass the check is 1.5 + 0.03 times the number of Trade Ships.

So, by the time you've reached the 100% mark, you'll have (100-15)/0.35 = 242.857 ships, yielding 8.78 titanium per trade. Of course, you also need 86 tradeposts to prevent the baseless hate :-)